# How to run amcl_demo in gazebo+RViz?

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo, amcl-demo.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,every one.
Now, I want to run amcl_demo in gazebo in my ROS(**indigo + ubuntu14.04 + kinect1**)

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=database/test0.yaml
```

but after I ran

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=database/test0.yaml
```

the terminal output some error info:

```
'[ERROR] [1462761356.977949263]: Map_server could not open database/test0.yaml.
 [ INFO] [1462761357.305058954, 74.440000000]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string      openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera- 0.2.5/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 631 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
[map_server-10] process has died [pid 11399, exit code 255, cmd /home/zuo/ros/ws/devel/lib/map_server/map_server database/test0.yaml __name:=map_server __log:=/home/zuo/.ros/log/94c0a0f6-158e-11e6-b559-005a39d84f79/map_server-10.log].
log file: /home/zuo/.ros/log/94c0a0f6-158e-11e6-b559-005a39d84f79/map_server-10*.log'
```

they said "No matching device found",but when I could ran gmapping in gazebo, it's OK!

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch
```

So , what's problem with me?
Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233890/how-to-run-amcl_demo-in-gazebo+rviz?/) by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding full path of your map file.  You can see launch file [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/amcl_demo.launch).

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/zuo/my_maps/some_map.yaml
```

**EDIT:** Not a problem, I'm using Tanzanian English too :) You can follow link (the file is in above link) in my answer, and look `map_file` parameter.  If it's searching package like this:

```
"$(find some_package)/$(arg map_file)"
```

you can use your folder's path in your `<workspace>/src/<PATH>` directly. If you didn't edit default lanunch file (the file is in above link), It's using full path(or full path in `TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE` environment variable default.).You can also create your own launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-05-09**:
I'm afraid it's not a path error.I try full path,but it also output next error info

```
process has died [pid 24354, exit code 255
```

In any case, thanks for your time.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-09**:
True one is full path. Leave path full before finding other problem.

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-05-09**:
I have used roslaunch gmapping in gazebo by relative path,and it's right.I think it maybe something wrong in launch file or .bashrc file.

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-05-09**:
What's different on environment when use amcl_demo and gmapping in gazebo?And I'm so sorry for my english,hope you could understand.
hhhhhhhhhhLOL

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-05-10**:
I've edited my answer.